# Client-side RadioButtonList validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 function IsChecked()
     {
    var rblActive = document.getElementById("<%=rblActive.ClientID %>");
    var item = rblActive.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var IsItemChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
     {
        if (item[i].checked) 
        {
        IsItemChecked = true;
        }

      }
        if (IsItemChecked == false) 
          {
          alert("Check Yes or No");
          rblActive.focus();
          return false;
           }
          return true;
      }
```

This is the code I tried. When control comes in the for loop, it directly comes out without any action even if the item in the radio button list is checked or not checked.

Comment: show some code, what have you try till now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same with jQuery also..

```
function ValidateControls() {
    var count = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            count++;
        }

    });

    if (count > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("No Row Selected");
        return false;
    }
}
```